# Can the canon r5 and r6 connect to a phone without that phone disconnecting from the internet

Tags: canon, file-transfer, apps

Using som old cameras I hade to connect to the cameras built in wifi network to remote control it and download images to my smartphone. This the resulted in my smartphone loosing internet access until I disconnected.

Have this been fixed in more recent models?
Can I connect to a canon r6 or r5 camera with the app without loosing internet connection? Bonus points if sharing images is easy.

To clarify: I do not neccecarily mean connect with wifi, I am asking if there is any method to do so, bluthoot or I guess a usb cable would also be considered capable

Comment: @Tetsujin I was hoping that newer cameras had implemented more sane protocols for connecting so that was not an issue anymore.

Comment: @Tetsujin why is that not a camera issue? If I could configure a more modern camera to use bluethoot for data trafic instead, or use the phones wifisharing to setup the network from the phone side or something, negotiating details with the camera using bluethoot, or for that matter just using bluethoot or similar to share wifi access details from phone to camera when they are both on wifi. The camera creating an access point is not a good idea in the first place so I asked if new cameras have other ways establish the connection that avoids the limitations of that.

Comment: You never mentioned bluetooth until now. I'm afraid I failed my mind-reading exams.

Comment: @Tetsujin no need to be sorry, I just pointed out I did not specify connection technology at all which was intentional, I don't care which protocols are used as long as it works so I wanted to avoid overspecifying.

Comment: What is the actual problem to be solved? Why do you need WiFi Internet access on the phone when you download images from the camera? Is it for photo sharing? Streaming? Something else?

Comment: What forced you to use wifi on "som old cameras"? What else have you tried?

Comment: It's not unreasonable to expect to use a multipurpose device such as a smartphone for more than one thing at a time. Perhaps the OP does not wish to miss notifications, texts, etc. while also transferring images to their phone?

Comment: Related: [Can the Canon 6D connect to a phone's WIFI hotspot and talk to the Canon app on that phone?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/100051/15871) - [Is there a Canon DSLR to transfer photos to a server directly?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/110620/15871) -  [How do I turn on the Bluetooth on my Snapbridge-enabled Nikon DLSR?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/88778/15871) - [How useful is wifi on a camera?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/113563/15871) - [What can I, as a software developer, do with “Wi-Fi builtin” mode on cameras?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/77426/15871)

Comment: @Michael C you are correctly pointing out that I do not want to loose all other use of my phone when out taking photos. And I at the same time want easy sharing of photos to instagram and the like.

Comment: @null I am asking about the existance of a feature on a camera I do not own (Canon R6 or R5) to be able to make an informed decission if I decide to buy it.

Comment: @lijat your premise that you need a new camera is simply wrong. You are too focused on blaming it on the "old camera". I just connected my phone to my 12 year old DSLR and it worked like a charm, without losing internet connectivity.

Comment: @null nice observation, I will have to try again, if this is something introduced in an ios update it might work now

Answer (score 3):

This is most likely an issue on the phone end, not the camera end. Most (all?) phones assume that if WiFi is enabled, that it can use that for internet connectivity, instead of shuffling internet stuff through the cellular network. I have not seen a phone yet that will continue to use e.g. 4G/5G cellular connections for internet access while WiFi is attached to something else. That's not to say that it couldn't be done - just that the software on phones these days just isn't written that way. Maybe an interesting thing to suggest/request to the Android or IOS developers....

Comment: This does not answer the question and also presumes that the camera acts as a wifi hotspot.

Comment: It answers the question as asked. If you want a bluetooth solution, mention it in your question, otherwise everyone will waste their time as I did, talking about wifi.

Comment: @Tetsujin, It does not, I am asking if there is any way to do that not for any specific technology. Added an edit to clarify

Comment: @lijat but some specific technology _is_ the way to do that. You are trying to make your question more generic, which is a *bad* idea. It is not the goal to create one super generic answer that will solve this problem once and for all for every phone, camera and connectivity technology, the goal is to answer your *specific* problem. But you are stubbornly refusing to provide concrete information about what camera and phone you have and what your are trying to do.

Comment: @null there was an edit that removed which camera I was asking about. I reverted that. Is the question more clear now?

Comment: _I have not seen a phone yet that will continue to use e.g. 4G/5G cellular connections for internet access while WiFi is attached to something else._ You're describing tethering. While the tethering connection (say, laptop->phone) is initiated from the tethered device, not from the phone, the phone's wifi is definitely being used as a WAP.

Comment: @lijat I removed that because from your question it didn't look like you were asking for those two camera models specifically, my bad.

Answer (score 2):

> Using som old cameras I hade to connect to the cameras built in wifi network to remote control it and download images to my smartphone. This the resulted in my smartphone loosing internet access until I disconnected.
>
> Have this been fixed in more recent models?

According to [this article](https://jrklein.com/2019/04/06/using-mobile-internet-data-while-connected-to-a-wifi-network-ios-android/) you can have both a wifi connection and internet connection over cellular network in parallel since at least Android 8 and iOS 12.

> To clarify: I do not neccecarily mean connect with wifi, I am asking if there is any method to do so, bluthoot or I guess a usb cable would also be considered capable

An [USB OTG cable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_On-The-Go) will allow you to connect a card reader to your phone just like you would connect it to a computer and transfer files from the card to your phone with a suitable app, if your phone supports that (many modern smartphones do)

You can also connect to the usb port of the camera directly of course.

Answer (score 2):

A few can. For instance, for Canon cameras that have an external Wireless File Transmitter (WFT) module available, the external WFT module will allow an encrypted connection to an external WiFi network. Maybe it will work with your phone's "hotspot". Though most users seem to say it works better when the AFT module is connected to the same WiFi network as the one to which the phone is connected.

Even those Canon cameras which allow logging onto an external network using an external WFT module do not allow the same using the camera's internal WiFi radio, if the camera has such an internal radio. The internal radio can only host a WiFi network but not connect as a client to another network.

The WFT modules for cameras that do not have a built-in RJ-45 ethernet port also provide one.

Current and past cameras with WFT modules available include the 1-Series bodies (EOS 1D X Mark III, EOS 1D Mark IV, etc.), recent 5-Series bodies (EOS 5D Mark IV, 5D Mark III, etc.), the EOS 7D Mark II, and the just released EOS R5 and R6 mirrorless bodies. Some of the C-series of cinema cameras, such as the C300 Mark II, can also use WFT modules. For the 1-Series/C-series the WFTs plug directly into a proprietary port on the camera. For the 5D/7D series, it's a brick that connects via USB3 which can be used as a dongle or attached to the base of the camera using the 1/4"-16 tripod receiver. For the R5 and R6 it is in the form of battery grip with vertical controls as well as the WiFi functionality and an RJ-45 port for a wired ethernet connection.

Be prepared to pay for the privilege, though. Most of these cameras are not exactly cheap, and the WFT modules themselves run in the high three figures.

On the other end of the connection, there are a few smartphones that have the ability to maintain two connections at the same time. This allows them to join the camera's ad hoc network using one transmitter/antenna while connecting to the internet via WiFi or cellular network (5G, 4G, LTE+, etc.) with another transmitter/antenna. These rare phones aren't exactly cheap, either.

Comment: The original question was asking specifically about the canon R6 and R5, this answers an edited question.

Comment: It answered the state the question was in when the answer was written. It does include information about the R5 and R6, though. You need to spend an extra $999 to get the WFT-R10 for your world area (there are different versions fro different WiFi radio bands in different world areas) to be able to log onto another WiFi network as a client.